How do I write a function that changes thumb size based on slider value?
I'm pretty new to JavaScript so I've been messing around and teaching myself how to use the functions. I'm trying to use setInterval to make a function that constantly changes the size of the thumb based on the value of the slider.
I tried to use getElementById and other things and I can't figure it out.
Here is the HTML:
<input type="range" class="javaRange" id="rangeInput2" name="rangeInput2" min="0" max="1000" value="0"
    oninput="amount2.value=rangeInput2.value">
    <output id="amount2" name="amount2" for="rangeInput2">0</output>

Here is the CSS (The slider is customized):
<style>
.javaRange {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #cdfffe;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}



.javaRange::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #00918f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 0;
}
</style>

and here is the JavaScript that I have currently:
<script>
const constant = 0.12;
const thumbValue = document.getElementById("rangeInput2").value;
function thumbSize(){
  document.getElementById("rangeInput2").style.width = 20 + parseInt(thumbValue) + "px";
  document.getElementById("rangeInput2").style.height = 20 + parseInt(thumbValue) + "px";
};
setInterval(thumbSize());
</script>

I've tried so many things. please help!
EDIT:
I just got an answer that really helped but it raised another question. am I able to specifically target thumb size? Here is the line of code I'm using:
document.getElementById("rangeInput2").style.width = 20 + parseInt(thumbValue) + "px";

It worked except that it was changing the size of the entire slider, and I only wanted to change the size of the thumb.

That's contrary to expectations.  Traditionally, the size of the thumb is determined by the size of the range, not by the value of the slider.  If there are only a few options, the thumb is quite large.  You should surprise your users.

What exactly is not working as expected? Is this a JS issue, an HTML issue, or a CSS issue?

Get rid of the setInterval(). You should be listening to events. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#javascript

You don't need to use setInterval; just call thumbSize() in that oninput handler.


function thumbSize() {
  const ri = document.getElementById("rangeInput2");
  const thumbValue = ri.value;
  const size = 50 + parseInt(thumbValue);
  ri.style.width = ri.style.height = `${size}px`;
};
thumbSize(); // Once, for initialization
.javaRange {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #cdfffe;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.javaRange::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #00918f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 0;
}
<input type="range" class="javaRange" id="rangeInput2" name="rangeInput2" min="0" max="1000" value="0" oninput="thumbSize()">




The event handler gives you the source of the event, no need to getElementById. Probably a good idea to suggest that.

Using setInterval most certainly isnt the best solution here, however its not the reason it doesnt work. There's at least 2 reasons it wont work here:

setInterval expects the first parameter to be a function. Your code reads: setInterval(thumbSize()); Which takes the result of the thumbSize function and sends that to setInterval. What you actually want is setInterval(thumbSize).
Getting the current value is only done once and not every time it re-sizes:

// Here we get the value, that value will never change
const thumbValue = document.getElementById("rangeInput2").value;
function thumbSize(){
  // use the never changing value to resize?? -- Problem here
  document.getElementById("rangeInput2").style.width = 20 + parseInt(thumbValue) + "px";
  document.getElementById("rangeInput2").style.height = 20 + parseInt(thumbValue) + "px";
};

You can simply move the thumbValue inside the function to fix that.
There may be other problems but those are 2 definite issues.

Please dont do this for real code you plan on shipping to someone. The correct answer is to listen for the value changing and react to that. But for playing around with code its certainly a "reasonable" approach
